# What is the best way to handle webhook APIs in Hapi.js?

Tags: webhooks, hapi.js

A common webhook-style API practice is for an API consumer to receive the webhook request, respond with 204 No Content, close the connection, and then process the request. Hapi.js does not send a reply object until nextTick, which means that the handler function must return.

Separating the request processing into a separate function and calling it with nextTick still causes the processing to occur before the reply object is sent. setTimeout works, but this has negative performance implications.

Hapi's request extensions seemed like an option, but are attached to all requests, regardless of path, which adds an unnecessary overhead to other requests.

Express.js has a response.send() method that immediately sends the response. Ideally, Hapi would have something like this.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  Does it matter that the webhook doesn't get responded to asap?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution. Yes, it matters very much that the webhook request receives a response and properly closes the connection before my app continues performing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use `setImmediate` for any processing that should happen after the response is sent and connection closed. Hapi sends the `reply` on `nextTick`. `setImmediate` events will be processed after `nextTick` events.

See example: https://gist.github.com/jeremiahlee/3689e8b4d1513c375b1e